# What is the difference between using @Autowired and AUTOWIRE_BY_TYPE?

Tags: java, spring

```java
private void processBeanDefinitions(Set<BeanDefinitionHolder> beanDefinitions) 
      definition.setAutowireMode(AbstractBeanDefinition.AUTOWIRE_BY_TYPE);
}
```

What is the difference between  AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_NO and AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_BY_TYPE?

Comment: I noticed that Spring created BeanDefinition using AUTOWIRE_NO, we can use @autowire annotation to complete attribute injection. But mybatis-spring creates BeanDefinition using AUTOWIRE_BY_TYPE and also provides a set method. What is the difference between the two?

Comment: The autowire mode and `@Autowired` are not related. The `AUTOWIRE_BY_TYPE` predates the annotation support and would try to autowire properties (ie. setters) on beans based on the type they expect. So a `setDataSource(DataSource ds)` would get automatically autowired with a datasource typed bean. Again this is **NOT** related to annotation based autowiring.

Comment: @soranico, editing your comment into your question might be a good idea.

Comment: @M.Deinum That is to say Autowired annotation is just a technique to inject
attributes?

Comment: It is explicitly telling to autowire that dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AUTOWIRE_NO - no external autowiring at all.

AUTOWIRE_BY_TYPE - autowiring bean properties by type.

[REF](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/AbstractBeanDefinition.html)

There is another answer that explains this difference - [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21103239/7505731)

Comment: How does @autowired work when we use NO? What is the difference with TYPE?

Comment: It isn't related to `@Autowired`.