# Why @Autowired still works while @Bean annotation's autowire property default value is Autowire.NO?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Here is the @Bean source code:

```
    @Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Documented
    public @interface Bean {
        @AliasFor("name")
        String[] value() default {};
    
        @AliasFor("value")
        String[] name() default {};
    
        Autowire autowire() default Autowire.NO;
    
        String initMethod() default "";
    
        String destroyMethod() default "(inferred)";
    }
```

I find that autowire's default value is Autowire.NO, but when I use this bean with @Autowired it still works, is it behavior by default or by some kind of convention?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34172888/difference-between-bean-and-autowired - This may give you additional details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the documentation:](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework/spring-context/5.0.2.RELEASE/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html#autowire--)

> public abstract org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowire autowire
> Are dependencies to be injected via convention-based autowiring by name or type?
> Note that this autowire mode is just about externally driven autowiring based on bean property setter methods by convention, analogous to XML bean definitions.
>
> The default mode does allow for annotation-driven autowiring. "no" refers to externally driven autowiring only, not affecting any autowiring demands that the bean class itself expresses through annotations.
> See Also:
>
> Autowire.BY_NAME, Autowire.BY_TYPE
> Default:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowire.NO

In other words, that property has nothing to do with how your bean is injected into other beans, but how the bean's own properties are implicitly autowired.

By default (`Autowire.NO`) means that Spring will not attempt to call setter methods unless annotated with `@Autowired` explicitly

[This was also answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020187/in-spring-what-does-autowire-autowire-no-do)

Comment: Very clear, thanks a lot!